# How to stop unwanted redirect ? (redirect headers are blank , no referrer)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am facing a challenge someone bought a domain let say www.abc.eu and he has redirected all its traffic towards our website www.abc.com. So when a user hit www.abc.eu it redirects and open our website and user think .eu is our branch.

He is performing fishing attacks on his region users and offering jobs to people on our behave.

How can we stop this redirect?. Keep the following situation in mind.

1. www.abc.com (Is hosted on shared hosting and our hosting company have said they cannot do anything in this case).
2. www.abc.com is wordpress site and .htaccess blocks don't work in this situation as we don't have "referrer" or "host"value with the traffic coming from his domain.

Comment: Perhaps a question better suited for http://serverfault.com.

Comment: Point 2 seems strange, no referrer or host? See [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59872/unwanted-redirect-from-a-domain-to-my-site) post.

Comment: As commented before, a server approach could be a better idea. But, if it's "impossible", or at last, take to longer, you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to filter and do some action about. It's not the best solution, just a temporary one.

Comment: @PhilipThomson - i have verified it. HTTP_REFERER is empty.                                                                                           I have applied this in .htaccess file 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://google.com [R,L]                                                                            Note: If this is a "redirect" (as in a 301 HTTP redirect) then the HTTP_REFERER won't be set to unwanteddomain.com. The HTTP_REFERER will only be set in this case if the user was following a link from unwanteddomain.com